# Find a shoot angle looking at a photograph

Tags: geometry, angle

Is there a way to find which anlges a photograph is shoot from? Using a protractor or some other tool. At least for objects which we can say are staying at right angle. For example for an item on a store shelf.[image: Example of shelf]

Comment: For this, we'd need to find out the angle of the camera from all three axes. There *should* be multiple solutions.

Comment: If you assume that the bottles are standing approximately vertically, and that the floor is horizontal and the rectangular, then you can find vanishing points for three orthogonal directions in the scene. That should be enough to reconstruct the camera’s rotation relative to the scene. Since you have the vanishing points of orthogonal directions, you can also recover the effective focal distance. You’ll need to make some further simplifying assumptions about the camera’s intrinsic matrix, though.

Comment: amd, thank you! That's the most valuable answer I had for days. Could someone also provide any practical solution for the photo above? So it could be used as an example.